# EC2: Security group firewall rules across multiple regions with AutoScaling

Tags: amazon-ec2, firewall

For geographic redundancy and performance reasons we are going to be setting up a number of EC2 servers across multiple regions that will scale up and down on demand using Amazon's AutoScaling.  We however have a somewhat unique requirement in that every server across all the regions needs to be able to communicate with each other.  Whilst it's pretty trivial to set up the firewall to allow this in a single region, it is not obvious how one achieves this across regions as referencing security groups in the firewall from other regions is not supported.

Does anyone know what is the best way to ensure that all of our servers have access to each other on a particular port?  Remember, servers will be added and removed by Amazon's AutoScaling so entering the IP addresses manually is going to become outdated quite quickly.  I am hoping there is a way of achieving this through configuration as opposed to having to make API calls every time a server is added or removed by AutoScaling.

Comment: did you find a solution to this?  I have a similar requirement + hit the same issue.  Or is adding via ip the only way?

Comment: Unfortunately not.  We looked at a number of solutions, one of them being vCider, but in the end we decided to use signed certificates and STunnel to open up ports between our servers securely.  I believe the way Amazon EC2 is built, it is intentionally configured so that each region is completely independent of every other region, so in turn these types of dependencies between regions is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe this is possible. You can try to use the security group id instead of the name but i'm not sure that those work cross region. I just tried it out and couldn't get it to work. The rule was created just fine but there's no guarantee that the security group i added as actually from my account since you can in fact add security groups across accounts. It is most likely possible with a VPN connection if you have one since the VPN gives you much more control over firewall rules, however I've never tried it.

All of that being said. I think you should revisit the requirements of your application. I don't know why you need to connect between the two regions, I understand your goal is achieving geographical redundancy. However, requiring the two environments to connect to each other throws a red flag for me when considering fault tolerance. If you're environments are connected in any way you run the risk of a complete failure even if one environment fails. What purpose other than latency or fault tolerance does launching instances in two regions provide? My point being if the servers need a rule in the security group your environments are probably too connected and you gain no benefit by having two geographical locations.

Each of the EC2 regions are isolated to help provide promote strong architectural design decisions. They also want to isolate any issues to a single region, which is what you should be striving for as well.

Comment: It's all about latency, and is one of the primaru reasons why we're adding regions. Clients connected in each region need to receive messages from other regions in real time, so isolating the regions completely is unfortunately pointless. We have built in fault tolerance negating dependency in one region on another, but it's imperative that each server in each region can connect to another region whilst it's available. So unfortunately your answer has not helped at all as there is a valid reason for these instances to have this level of access.

Comment: "If your environments are connected in any way" - They might have to be connected, e.g. for datastore replication. It's easy to replicate the infra in another region on demand if you have a great configuration management setup but it's a different story for data replication as it has to be continuous for the data to have any validity.

Comment: Right, sometimes you cannot avoid it. Hopefully if you need that kind of high availability you're using software for your database which supports multi region replication. Aside from the datastores/databases you should really try to avoid intra region communication.